# What's the best way to identify an exception thrown by the AWS SDK for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

Usually I create/use error classes to identify the origin or the error and handle appropriately - something like this:

Error class example:

```
class ApplicationError extends Error {
    get name() {
        return this.constructor.name;
    }
}

class DatabaseError extends ApplicationError { }

module.exports = {
    ApplicationError,
    DatabaseError
}
```

Error handling example:

```
const { DatabaseError } = require('./error');

async dbUpdater() {
    try {
        await this._updateDb();
    } catch (err) {
        if (err instanceof DatabaseError) {
            // handle db error...
        } else {
            throw error;
        }
    }
}
```

However all exceptions throw by the AWS SDK for JS V2 use the default 'Error' class instead of something more useful like 'AWSError'. What is the best way to identify an exception thrown by the AWS SDK for JavaScript so it can be handled accordingly?

Are there properties common across all AWS errors I can look for?

**Edit**: error.code seems to be common across all AWS errors but I cannot test for that property alone as non AWS errors are thrown that contain a 'code' property. Are other properties common across all AWS errors I could also look for? I can't see a page in the documentation with this information.

Comment: Log the error message to determine what the issue is. Most error messages are detailed enough to figure out.

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad that approach works if I want to handle a specific AWS exception, I want to be able to handle all AWS exceptions in a similar way - naturally different codes/messages are used for each.

Comment: It's going to be complicated, but you can automate Error Handling with AWS Step Functions, look it up

Comment: "*Are there properties common across all AWS errors I can look for?*" - yes, [it's `error.code`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Response.html#error-property)

Comment: @Bergi error.code is used in other non AWS errors so I couldn't check for that key alone. Are any of the other AWS error properties common across all errors?

Comment: By looking through the SDK it looks like 'code', 'message' and 'time' are the non-optional properties common across AWS errors.

Comment: "*non AWS errors are thrown that contain a 'code' property*" - but they should use different codes, right? The code is what you should be using to decide whether/how to handle the error appropriately. If you just want to know "Does this error somehow come from AWS", I don't think that's useful or possible. (If you're not going to wrap every sdk call into `convertExceptionsToAwsError`).